# Android Video Player libraries with cache video

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-video-player

I developed android app which is based on video listing,I face some problems that are,

1.When scroll a listview video need  auto play

2.Need pause,stop,resume and full screen mode

3.Every time video is streaming

4.How to make cache videos and play without stream

Is there any Lib or reference link,and advance Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

i suggest [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer), here is a good [sample](https://github.com/everalbum/ExoPlayer/tree/ae0132d3224e7a4428e068fdc6d7db0fdc17f411/demo/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/demo/recyclerview)
for caching, you can use [VideoCache](https://github.com/danikula/AndroidVideoCache) or [OkHttpDataSource](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2/extensions/okhttp)