# How to cache a video in background in android?

Tags: android, caching, video, android-video-player

I am building an android application where a user can view some listed video. Those videos are categories into some channel. Once a channel is selected by user I want to cache all the video related to that channel in my cache memory so can play the video when there is no internet also.

Can anyone have more understanding about video cache without playing please help me in understanding how I can achieve this task.

Right now I am able to cache video If it's played using some library.

Comment: I suggest you to use VideoCache or ExoPlayer. Check this post https://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585763/android-video-player-libraries-with-cache-video&ved=2ahUKEwibuf2X4tXZAhXCyqQKHZKOCUIQFjAEegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw0C1o0_xkwtlscEiVSnWE8d

Comment: @FazalHussain I have used both. But none of them support background caching of video

Comment: is it possible to cache multiple video `URL` in background thread  without using any `VideoView/Exoplayer` ? I am able to cache video only when it is streaming/playing in player using this lib https://github.com/danikula/AndroidVideoCache

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have find the following working solution for caching video in background (single/multiple) using below lib, no need of `player/video_view`.use `AsyncTaskRunner`

[Videocaching Lib](http://github.com/danikula/AndroidVideoCache)

Add following in line in your gradle file

```
compile 'com.danikula:videocache:2.7.0'
```

> Since we just need to kick start the prefetching, no need to do anything in `while` loop.
>
> Or we can use `ByteArrayOutputStream` to write down the data to disk.

```
 URL url = null;
 try {
       url = new URL(cachingUrl(cachingUrl));

       InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();
       int bufferSize = 1024;
       byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
       int length = 0;
       while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
             //nothing to do
       }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

> Important code from lib. to do

Create static instance in application class using following code

```
private HttpProxyCacheServer proxy;

public static HttpProxyCacheServer getProxy(Context context) {
    Applications app = (Applications) context.getApplicationContext();
    return app.proxy == null ? (app.proxy = app.newProxy()) : app.proxy;
}

private HttpProxyCacheServer newProxy() {
    //return new HttpProxyCacheServer(this);
    return new HttpProxyCacheServer.Builder(this)
            .cacheDirectory(CacheUtils.getVideoCacheDir(this))
            .maxCacheFilesCount(40)
            .maxCacheSize(1024 * 1024 * 1024)
            .build();
}
```

Write following code in your activity to pass `url`

```
public String cachingUrl(String urlPath) {

 return Applications.getProxy(this).getProxyUrl(urlPath, true);

}
```

Comment: This library is showing Latest commit on 24 Jul 2018... are there any by big players or actively maintained like Glide is for images

Comment: @DragonFire avoid to use above library its bugy library

Comment: @BhaveshJethani is there any alternative to this library? because I need the same features in my live project. thanks.

Comment: @RaoArsalan https://github.com/iambaljeet/TikTok ViewPager2 and ExoPlayer2. default android catching.